# How to avoid p. after pp. in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, citing

Can anyone tell me how to avoid mentioning both the pp. and the p. in footnote citing of an article? I kinda find it ugly and redundant. Here is what I mean:

> 18J.R.R. Tolkien. “On Fairy-Stories”. In: The Monsters and the Critics and Other Essays. Ed. by Christopher Tolkien. London: George Allen and Unwin, 1983, pp. 109–161, p. 141.

In this case, I need to mention p. 141, but I wish to remove pp. 109–161. I don't want to have pp. omitted in all citations, but only when a specific page is mentioned.

I'm using the following:

```
\usepackage[bibstyle=verbose,citestyle=verbose-trad3,autocite=footnote,backend=bibtex,backref=true]{biblatex}
```

Answer (score 6):

`verbose` styles provide a new preamble option called `citepages`.

The options are:

- `citepages=permit`:  allows duplicates, i.e., the style will print both the pages/pagetotal and the postnote. This is the default setting;
- `citepages=suppress` unconditionally suppresses the pages/pagetotal fields in citations, regardless of the postnote;
- `citepages=omit` suppresses the pages/pagetotal only when the postnote is a page range;
- `citepages=separate` separates the pages/pagetotal from the number range postnote with a string a bib string (“especially”).

See the [`verbose` style example file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/70-style-verbose-biber.pdf) for more information.

Here's a MWE with `citepages=suppress`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bibstyle=verbose,citestyle=verbose-trad3,
            autocite=footnote,backend=bibtex,
            backref=true,citepages=suppress]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\autocite[141]{kant:kpv}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

> [image: mwe]

Comment: that's great, henrique, it worked! many thanks!