# How to suppress page numbers from bib-File if given in cite?

Tags: biblatex

in citations (not in the bibliograpy) I want to supress the page numbers from the bib-File if a number is given with the cite.

What I get:
[image]

What I want:

> 1 Emma Sigfridsson und Ulf Ryde. Comparison of methods for deriving
>   atomic chargesfrom the electrostatic potential and moments. In:
>   Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4(1998), <s>S. 377-395</s>, S. 591.

My mwe:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=ext-verbose-ibid,
  isbn=false, url=false, doi=false, eprint=false,
  dashed=false,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem\autocite[591]{sigfridsson}
ipsum\autocite[123]{sigfridsson}
dolor\autocite[592]{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: You'll want to look at the `citepages` option, see the `biblatex` documentation or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/138761/35864. `citepages=omit,` or `citepages=suppress,` might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you @moewe. This is exactly what I was looking for.