# Suppress field "pages" when page is specified in postnote with verbose citations

Tags: biblatex

I'm using the `ext-verbose-trad2` `biblatex` style. When I specify the page of the citation using the command `\cite` the output prints the `pages` field of the entry, resulting in a redundant page reference.

Here a brief code as an exemplification

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, openright, twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage[style = ext-verbose-trad2, articlein=false, firstinits=true, ibidpage=true]{biblatex}


\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@inbook{InbookCecchi, 
  author   = {Cecchi, C.},
  title= {Perseverare},
  bookauthor = {Cecchi, C.},
  booktitle = {Diabolic issues},
  editor = {Faffi, F. and Jollie, J. K.},
  date = {1980},
  pages = {15-18},
}

@article{ArticleTotti, 
  author   = {Totti, Q.},
  title= {Grammatica sbagliata},
  journaltitle = {Proceedings in errors},
  number = 12,
  volume = {XV},
  date = {2025},
  pages = {223-567},
}

\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

  \cite[16]{InbookCecchi}.

  \cite[240-251]{ArticleTotti}.

\end{document}
```

This gives the result:

[image]

I want to avoid the underlined pages reference, corresponding to the `pages` field in the respective entry, since I’m already specifying at which page I’m referring to.

Comment: It answers perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the `citepages` option.

The option is documented in [the `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) (pp. 62-63) and in [the `verbose-trad2` style example](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/75-style-verbose-trad2-biber.pdf) (pp. 2-3).

You probably want the effect of `citepages=omit,`, but you may also be interested in `citeopages=suppress,` or `citepages=separate,`

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, openright, twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[
  style=ext-verbose-trad2,
  firstinits=true, 
  articlein=false,
  ibidpage=true,
  citepages=omit,
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{InbookCecchi, 
  author     = {Cecchi, C.},
  title      = {Perseverare},
  bookauthor = {Cecchi, C.},
  booktitle  = {Diabolic issues},
  editor     = {Faffi, F. and Jollie, J. K.},
  date       = {1980},
  pages      = {15-18},
}
@article{ArticleTotti, 
  author       = {Totti, Q.},
  title        = {Grammatica sbagliata},
  journaltitle = {Proceedings in errors},
  number       = 12,
  volume       = {XV},
  date         = {2025},
  pages        = {223-567},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \cite[16]{InbookCecchi}

  \cite[240-251]{ArticleTotti}
\end{document}
```

[image: C. Cecchi. “Perseverare”. In: Diabolic issues. A cura di F. Faffi e J. K. Jollie. 1980, p. 16//Q. Totti. “Grammatica sbagliata”. Proceedings in errors XV.12 (2025), pp. 240–251]

Comment: I just noticed it is a duplicate question! https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/542846/how-to-suppress-page-numbers-from-bib-file-if-given-in-cite
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138761/how-to-avoid-p-after-pp-in-biblatex

Comment: Thank you so much, anyway

Comment: @PaoloPolesana I thought it would have to be, but I couldn't find the duplicate when I searched. Thanks for finding those. I voted to close the question as a duplicate to avoid further duplication of content.