# How to handle multiple citations with multiple pages using a bib file?

Tags: biblatex, pandoc-citeproc, rmarkdown

Using R markdown, I'm duplicating citations in my bib file to cite the same entry using different pages:

```
@article{devers_2011_34,
  title = {I know how to do the play now: A Part of Willy Loman in Synecdoche, New York},
  author = {Devers, Rebecca},
  journal = {The Arthur Miller Journal},
  volume = {6},
  number = {2},
  year = {2011},
  pages = {34},
  publisher = {The Arthur Miller Society}
}

@article{devers_2011_33,
  title = {I know how to do the play now: A Part of Willy Loman in Synecdoche, New York},
  author = {Devers, Rebecca},
  journal = {The Arthur Miller Journal},
  volume = {6},
  number = {2},
  year = {2011},
  pages = {33},
  publisher = {The Arthur Miller Society}
}
```

Writing `(@citation, pagenumber)` is wrong since I'm using full citation and some times the page comes after a URL.

Is this the right way to add pages to a citation?

(some additional context: https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles/issues/4795)

Comment: Oh hang on, the linked GitHub issue suggests you are using a CSL file to format your bibliography and citation. Then your citations and bibliography are not generated by LaTeX, so the question would be off-topic here.

Comment: I am using R markdown. the tag `biblatex-chicago` was a mistake. I want to use LaTeX to cite but I keep reading that it isn't possible since R Markdown uses `pandoc-citeproc`. I am slightly confused.

Comment: @moewe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/544614/latex-citation-in-r-markdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the LaTeX side of things the correct way to deal with this is to have only one `.bib` entry whose `pages` field contains the complete page range of the article.

If you refer to a particular page of the article in citations, you use the optional postnote argument to give the page number.

```
\autocite[34]{devers_2011}
```

It is the job of the citation style to ensure that the page reference comes out 'correctly'. (Some 'verbose'/'note' citation styles that produce full citations indeed have an option to replace the contents of the `pages` field with the postnote. For the standard styles this option is called `citepages`, see [How to avoid p. after pp. in biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/138761/35864).)

You have tagged your question with `biblatex-chicago` and with that package I get

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{devers_2011,
  title   = {I know how to do the play now:
             A Part of Willy Loman in Synecdoche, New York},
  author  = {Devers, Rebecca},
  journal = {The Arthur Miller Journal},
  volume  = {6},
  number  = {2},
  year    = {2011},
  pages   = {25-45},
  url     = {https://www.jstor.org/stable/42909473},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\null\vfill % only for the example
Lorem \autocite[34]{devers_2011}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Cite: "Rebecca Devers, “I know how to do the play now: A Part of Willy Loman in Synecdoche, New York,” The Arthur Miller Journal 6, no. 2 (2011): 34, https://www.jstor.org/stable/42909473." Bib:"Devers, Rebecca. “I know how to do the play now: A Part of Willy Loman in Synecdoche, New York.” The Arthur Miller Journal 6, no. 2 (2011): 25–45. https://www.jstor.org/stable/42909473."]

So when a postnote is present it automatically replaces the `pages` field in citations. This should produce the desired result.

---

Note that it might be nicer to use `eprint` for JSTOR links, but I explicitly used the URL to show that things work with a URL.

```
@article{devers_2011,
  title      = {I know how to do the play now:
                A Part of Willy Loman in Synecdoche, New York},
  author     = {Devers, Rebecca},
  journal    = {The Arthur Miller Journal},
  volume     = {6},
  number     = {2},
  year       = {2011},
  pages      = {25-45},
  eprint     = {42909473},
  eprinttype = {jstor},
}
```